# Why does my Django form keeps saying "this field is required"

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm a beginner at Django. My registration page is making my form invalid and it keeps printing the same error even though both the password fields are filled and they are the same. I have only attached any codes that are relevant to the password fields

Error: `<ul class="errorlist"><li>password1<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>password2<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>__all__<ul class="errorlist nonfield"><li>Passwords do not match.</li></ul></li></ul>`

forms.py:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    password1 = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'name': 'password1',
            'id': 'floatingPassword',
            'placeholder':'Password',
        }),
    )

    password2 = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'name': 'password2',
            'id': 'floatingConfirmPassword',
            'placeholder':'Confirm password',
        }),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'password1',
            'password2',
            ]

    # Compare password
    def clean(self):
        self.cleaned_data = super().clean()

        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match.")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

views.py (In prototype)

```
def register(request):
    # Create a new form
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = RegisterForm()
        return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})

    # When the user submits the form
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        # Check if the form is valid
        if form.is_valid():
            print('FORM is valid!')
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            form.save()
            #user = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            #messages.success(request, f"Account has been created for {user}")
            # UPDATE THE URL LINK IN THE FUTURE
            return redirect('/login')

        else:
            print('Form is not valid')
            print(form.errors)
            #messages.error(request, 'Error processing your request')
            return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

register.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0">
        <!--Load bootstrap library-->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>Sign Up | Portfolio</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form class="needs-validation" novalidate method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}

                    <div class="row g-2 col-md-12 mb-3">
                        <div class="form-floating col-md-6">
                            {{ form.password1 }}
                            <label for="floatingPassword" class="form-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="valid-feedback"></div>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                Please enter a password.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating col-md-6">
                            {{ form.password2 }}
                            <label for="floatingConfirmPassword" class="form-label">Enter password again</label>
                            <div class="valid-feedback"></div>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                Enter the password again.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 text-center">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn.lg" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </form>
              <script>
                    // Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
                    (function () {
                    'use strict'

                    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
                    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

                    // Loop over them and prevent submission
                    Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
                        .forEach(function (form) {
                        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                            if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                            event.preventDefault()
                            event.stopPropagation()
                            }

                            form.classList.add('was-validated')
                        }, false)
                        })
                    })()
              </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you remove the js in your html file, does it work?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But it works if I placed the clean function at views.py instead